# Кнопка-слайдер (конфликт скриптов)

Tags: jquery

Добрый день!
Подскажите пожалуйста, как решить следующую проблему:
Если в js-фаиле присутствует код кнопки-слайдера, то перестает работать Datepicker.
Так же, если в html документе содержится блок с данной кнопкой, то все работает, а если данного блока нет, то и Datepicker не работает.

[ВОТ ССЫЛКА](http://jsfiddle.net/Alex83/gDt24/7/).
Удаляем последний скрипт (button-slider), и Datepicker перестает работать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[[@markuper](/users/5928/markuper)](/users/5928/markuper), все правильно определил ошибку но не расшифровал до конца. После части кода:

```
// zoom image
$('a.increase').toggle(function() {
    $(this).prev().animate({'width': '+=275px'}, 450);
    return false;
}, function() {
    $(this).prev().animate({'width': '-=275px'}, 450);
    return false;
});
```

Идет вызов вызов функции **buttonSlider();**. Убираем этот вызов и всё работает.

**UPD**

```
if($('#slider').length > 0){
    buttonSlider();
}
```

Comment: Да, но если я уберу вызов, то как запустить buttonSlider()?

Comment: Как-то всё запутано. В общем, не могу понять всю подноготную данной задачи, но можно сделать следующим образом - проверять наличие кнопки в DOM и вызов функци делать, только если таковая найдена. Код смотрите в апдейте ответа.

Comment: Deonis, спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Потому что когда удаляете слайдер, buttonSlider() - стает undefined.

Comment: @Deonis, добрый день. Подскажите пожалуйста, возможно ли сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на "бегунок" (#runner), также происходило переключение.